# kubeadm init success when i execute kubeadm join error

Tags: kubernetes

Below are kubelet logs:

**journalctl -u kubelet**

```
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984082  105187 container_manager_linux.go:265] "Container manager verified user specified cgroup-root exists" cgroupRoot=[]
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984260  105187 container_manager_linux.go:270] "Creating Container Manager object based on Node Config" nodeConfig={"RuntimeCgroupsName":"","SystemCgroupsName":"","KubeletCgroupsName":"","KubeletOOMScoreAdj":-999,"ContainerRuntime":"","CgroupsPerQOS":true,"CgroupRoot":"/","CgroupDriver":"cgroupfs","KubeletRootDir":"/var/lib/kubelet","ProtectKernelDefaults":false,"KubeReservedCgroupName":"","SystemReservedCgroupName":"","ReservedSystemCPUs":{},"EnforceNodeAllocatable":{"pods":{}},"KubeReserved":null,"SystemReserved":null,"HardEvictionThresholds":[],"QOSReserved":{},"CPUManagerPolicy":"none","CPUManagerPolicyOptions":null,"TopologyManagerScope":"container","CPUManagerReconcilePeriod":10000000000,"ExperimentalMemoryManagerPolicy":"None","ExperimentalMemoryManagerReservedMemory":null,"PodPidsLimit":-1,"EnforceCPULimits":true,"CPUCFSQuotaPeriod":100000000,"TopologyManagerPolicy":"none","TopologyManagerPolicyOptions":null}
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984275  105187 topology_manager.go:138] "Creating topology manager with none policy"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984280  105187 container_manager_linux.go:301] "Creating device plugin manager"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984296  105187 state_mem.go:36] "Initialized new in-memory state store"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984324  105187 kubelet.go:399] "Kubelet is running in standalone mode, will skip API server sync"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984486  105187 kuberuntime_manager.go:257] "Container runtime initialized" containerRuntime="containerd" version="1.7.2" apiVersion="v1"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984588  105187 volume_host.go:74] "KubeClient is nil. Skip initialization of CSIDriverLister"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: W0817 20:44:27.984665  105187 csi_plugin.go:189] kubernetes.io/csi: kubeclient not set, assuming standalone kubelet
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: W0817 20:44:27.984673  105187 csi_plugin.go:266] Skipping CSINode initialization, kubelet running in standalone mode
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984774  105187 server.go:1232] "Started kubelet"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.984950  105187 kubelet.go:1579] "No API server defined - no node status update will be sent"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.985252  105187 fs_resource_analyzer.go:67] "Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: E0817 20:44:27.985583  105187 cri_stats_provider.go:448] **"Failed to get the info of the filesystem with mountpoint" err="unable to find data in memory cache" mountpoint="/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"**
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: E0817 20:44:27.985597  105187 kubelet.go:1431] **"Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet" err="invalid capacity 0 on image filesystem"**
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.986046  105187 server.go:162] "Starting to listen" address="0.0.0.0" port=10250
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.986421  105187 server.go:462] "Adding debug handlers to kubelet server"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.986886  105187 server.go:194] "Starting to listen read-only" address="0.0.0.0" port=10255
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.987221  105187 ratelimit.go:65] "Setting rate limiting for podresources endpoint" qps=100 burstTokens=10
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.987296  105187 server.go:233] "Starting to serve the podresources API" endpoint="unix:/var/lib/kubelet/pod-resources/kubelet.sock"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.988656  105187 volume_manager.go:291] "Starting Kubelet Volume Manager"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.989310  105187 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:151] "Desired state populator starts to run"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.989337  105187 reconciler_new.go:29] "Reconciler: start to sync state"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.990935  105187 kubelet_network_linux.go:50] "Initialized iptables rules." protocol="IPv4"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.997393  105187 kubelet_network_linux.go:50] "Initialized iptables rules." protocol="IPv6"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.997411  105187 status_manager.go:213] "Kubernetes client is nil, not starting status manager"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:27.997417  105187 kubelet.go:2303] "Starting kubelet main sync loop"
Aug 17 20:44:27 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: E0817 20:44:27.997444  105187 kubelet.go:2327] "Skipping pod synchronization"** err="[container runtime status check may not have completed yet, PLEG is not healthy: pleg has yet to be successful]"**
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.006489  105187 cpu_manager.go:214] "Starting CPU manager" policy="none"
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.006497  105187 cpu_manager.go:215] "Reconciling" reconcilePeriod="10s"
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.006505  105187 state_mem.go:36] "Initialized new in-memory state store"
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.006608  105187 state_mem.go:88] "Updated default CPUSet" cpuSet=""
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.006619  105187 state_mem.go:96] "Updated CPUSet assignments" assignments={}
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.006623  105187 policy_none.go:49] "None policy: Start"
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.006803  105187 memory_manager.go:169] "Starting memorymanager" policy="None"
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.006812  105187 state_mem.go:35] "Initializing new in-memory state store"
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.006863  105187 state_mem.go:75] "Updated machine memory state"
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.007111  105187 manager.go:471] **"Failed to read data from checkpoint" checkpoint="kubelet_internal_checkpoint" err="checkpoint is not found"**
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.007209  105187 plugin_manager.go:118] "Starting Kubelet Plugin Manager"
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: E0817 20:44:28.011866  105187 cadvisor_stats_provider.go:444] "Partial failure issuing cadvisor.ContainerInfoV2" err="partial failures: [\"/kubepods.slice/kubepods-besteffort.slice/kubepods-besteffort-pod7d59cb86_c85c_4527_83a3_6cc4b8376f2b.slice\": RecentStats: unable to find data in memory cache]"
Aug 17 20:44:28 k8s-master2 kubelet[105187]: I0817 20:44:28.089468  105187 
desired_state_of_world_populator.go:159] "Finished populating initial desired state of world"
```

**Below containerd info:**
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.618015133+08:00] starting containerd                           revision= version=1.7.2
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.626518379+08:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.627591151+08:00] **skip loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"...  error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 "modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-79-generic\n"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1**
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.627614220+08:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.627832133+08:00] **skip loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"...  error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs (ext4) must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1**
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.627845886+08:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"...  type=io.containerd.content.v1
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.627862616+08:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.627882029+08:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.627987471+08:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
WARN[2023-08-18T10:02:43.628007136+08:00] **failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper  error="devmapper not configured"**
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.628015548+08:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.628097057+08:00] skip loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"...  error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.628107121+08:00] loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"...  type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
WARN[2023-08-18T10:02:43.628123185+08:00] **could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin  error="devmapper not configured"**
INFO[2023-08-18T10:02:43.628132843+08:00] metadata content store policy set             policy=shared
WARN[2023-08-18T10:02:53.628647858+08:00] waiting for response from boltdb open         plugin=bolt

```
ubuntu 22  k8s 1.28  container 1.7.2
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), It is not only fair to those helping you in their spare time, but it also increases chances to receive an answer.